# Windows Firewall: Limit Google Chrome to only local network connections

Tags: google-chrome, firewall, windows-firewall

By local network, we mean within the subnet of the computer in question.

The idea is to disallow browsing of internet web pages, while allowing ones served locally.

Disallowing a particular local network is easy. For example in my case, this can be done by setting the Remote IP address scope to XXX.XXX.XXX.0/24. If I could only specify the complement set (i.e. non-local IP addresses) in this setting.

Is there a way to specify the complement set (or something similar, such as the complete set of remote addresses)? How to do this, assuming a Windows 7 OS?

Comment: You don't. You put a firewall on the edge of your network and you put a DENY rule in there.

Comment: The problem is, wouldn't this also block all other traffic such as those from Windows Update and antivirus update?

Comment: Well if you do it in Chrome, you could just load Internet Explorer. Or FireFox. Or Opera. Or Lynx. And bypass whatever arbitrary rule you have in places for Chrome. You could get a Layer-7 aware firewall that can inspect HTTP requests and permit requests to Windows Updates and Anti-Virus updates but nothing else.

Comment: I'll be using this in conjunction with parental controls, which will only allow a specific list of programs to be run.

Comment: In that case, I would be looking for parental control software that can do this on your behalf. I'm not particularly familiar with what's on offer (my kids are too young yet) but I'm sure that some of htem can do it.